# unique database entry per user in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-validation

I want the validate my create categories form this way:

User1 can create category "code"

User1 can not create another category "code"

User2 can create category "code"

User2 can not create another category "code"

I am trying to write this in my controller validator but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my validation rule:

```
'title' => 'required|max:100|unique:categories,title,user_id'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible with Laravel's Validator class. You can use the uniqueWith package however: https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator

Comment: Just check if there is a record made by user 1 before inserting

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom validation rule. Run the command:

```
php artisan make:rule UserCodePostLimit
```

within the generated class you will be able to have custom logic:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return Category::whereUserId($value)->count() !== 0
}
```

That way you will be able to register it in you validation rules:

```
'title' => ['required', 'max:100', new UserCodePostLimit]
```

All further  information can be found in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules